# Problem loading JSON resource in SWIFT package

Tags: json, swift, swift-package-manager

I am trying to load a JSON file that is bundled with a Swift package I am working on.

The JSON file is called `config.json` and it is located in my project under `/Sources/<Target>/data/config.json`

**UPDATE:** I have also added the resource to the target in the Package Description as follows:

```swift
...
.target(
    name: "MyPackage",
    resources: [
        .process("data/config.json")
    ]
),
...
```

I am trying to load it using the following code:

```swift
guard let sourcesURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "config", withExtension: "json") else {
    fatalError("Could not find config.json")
}
```

... but I keep getting `nil`.  Has anyone had an issue like this?  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `module`

```
Bundle.module.url(forResource: "config", withExtension: "json")
```

*And* you need to make sure the file is included when building by adding below to your target in Package.swift

```
resources: [
    .copy("data/config.json") //This could alo be .process
])
```

The above assumes that the resource is loaded from within the same package, if you want to load a resource from another package you can use the following general solution.

First define a constant in the package that holds the bundle identifier for the package, for instance in an extension to `Bundle`

```
extension Bundle {
    public static let myPackageNameBundleIdentifier = Bundle.module.bundleIdentifier!
}
```

And then create an instance of that Bundle when loading the resource in another package or the app

```
if let bundle = Bundle(identifier: Bundle.myPackageNameBundleIdentifier) {
    let url = bundle.url(forResource: "config", withExtension: "json")
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I had done that but forgot to mention it in the post (I've made that update so its more clear now).  That said, I am still getting `nil`

Comment: I just double checked this by adding a config file using the same path as you have and the code works fine. My answer assumes you are loading the resource from within the package though, could that be an issue.

Comment: Added a solution to load a resource from another package

Comment: The key for me was to use `Bundle.module` instead of `.main` as you pointed out.  Thanks @Joakim Danielson.